# Adding remote repo in Gradle - Manifest merger failed

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-build

I have added a remote maven repo to my android library project with below changes in my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: android-library
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:+
    }
}
apply plugin: maven
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url https://mvn.xxx.com/content/repositories/releases/
        credentials {
            username xxxxxx
            password yyyyyy
        }
    }
}
```

now it gives me a manifest merger error stating **my library package name is in conflict with remote repo's one.**

```
Execution failed for task :spuul:processDebugTestManifest.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : 
Attribute instrumentation#android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner@targetPackage
 value=(com.myLibrary.core.test) from manifestMerge1961318094990565159.xml:12:22
    is also present at com.remote.mavenrepo:1.0_7.64:16:9 value=(com.remote.mavenrepo)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:targetPackage"' to <instrumentation> 
    element at manifestMerge1961318094990565159.xml:11:5 to override
```

Not sure what to do to resolve this. Is there any way to skip creating test builds??
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

John Vuong response is correct, but contains a minor error: the XML namespace should be aliased to "tools", not "android".

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.android.interpolatorplayground.tests"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

In androidmanifest.xml files, 
add

```
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.android.interpolatorplayground.tests"
      **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools"**
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
```

....

```
    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.android.interpolatorplayground"
        **tools:replace="android:targetPackage"**
        android:label="Tests for com.example.android.interpolatorplayground" />
```

....
please refer here [Markers tools:replace](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger)

Comment: as  said  by  @rydnr it is "xmlns:tools"  and not   ":android" kindly  edit